# How to query data from three tables when two tables(with no relation) are connected with one

Tags: sql

I've tried to find the solution by googling, but got confused due to my requirement(s).  I want to query the total number of borrowers who have taken loan.  I did it with two tables (i.e. Table 1 and Table 2), but am unable to get a desired result with three tables.

Here are the Tables I've :

```
Table 1 [Connected with Table2 and Table3]

+--------------------------------------------------+
| Id | Name   |  AmountDue | GivenOn    | PayMode  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | John   |  5000      | 01/01/2015 | Weekly   |
| 2  | Shail  |  100       | 01/01/2015 | Custom   |
| 3  | James  |  500       | 01/01/2015 | Monthly  |
+--------------------------------------------------+

      Table 2 [For Weekly & Monthly Loan]

+-------------------------------------------------+
| Id | InstNo | InstAmt | DueON      | PaidON     |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1      |   2500  | 08/01/2015 | 08/01/2015 |
| 1  | 2      |   2500  | 15/01/2015 | 01/01/1900 | 
| 3  | 1      |    250  | 01/02/2015 | 01/01/1900 |
| 3  | 2      |    250  | 01/03/2015 | 01/01/1900 |
+-------------------------------------------------+

        Table 3 [For Custom]

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | Principle | Interest | TotalDue | DueON      | PaidAmt |   PaidON   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | 1000      | 20       | 1020     | 01/02/2015 |       0 | 01/01/1900 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to have the following result if I search for the borrowers whose PaidON Date = 01/01/1900

```
+-----------------------+
| Id | Name   | PayMode |
+-----------------------+
| 1  | John   | Weekly  |
| 2  | Shail  | Custom  |
| 3  | James  | Monthly |
+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Exists` and `Or` to determine if the id is in either table 2 or table 3

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    PayMode
FROM
    Table1 t1
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id AND t2.PaidOn = '01/01/1900')
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table3 t3 WHERE t3.Id = t1.Id AND t3.PaidOn = '01/01/1900')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Id,t1.Name,t1.Paymode
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN  table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
WHERE COALESCE(t2.PaidON,t3.PaidON)= '01/01/1900'
```

Comment: I've tried this, but showing the following error : 

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Table1.ID = Table2.ID LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.I' "

Don't know why it's not showing 'D' at the end.

Thank you for your efforts though.

Comment: I've rechecked but it's giving same "Missing operator" error.